# Is the ratio of a convex and linear function pseudoconvex?

Tags: convex-analysis

Both functions are differentiable. I know from Chandra[1](http://www.insa.nic.in/writereaddata/UpLoadedFiles/IJPAM/20005a7f_278.pdf) that the ratio of a nonnegative convex and a strictly positive concave function is pseudoconvex. Does this hold when the denominator is a strictly positive linear function? Can you direct me to the right reference?

Comment: Linear functions are concave, aren't they?